# PHP with Load Balanced Nodejs Backend on same server

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I'm using PHP for my frontend and Node.js for the backend and they are running on the same AWS server, I'm currently using pm2 to run 2 clusters of Node.js and PHP requests data from `localhost:NODE_PORT`

I'm now node balancing using NGINX on two different ports, so is it efficient to run PHP requests over 'DOMAINNAME/api' instead of localhost?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you sending HTTP requests from PHP to the NodeJS server?

Comment: @HtmHell yes, php sends requests to nodejs over localhost, but with nginx i can't do it, only with the domain name, so is that right ?

Comment: I don't understand why are you using both PHP and NodeJS. If it's optional for you - I would use only NodeJs/PHP. If you must have them both, then instead of HTTP requests you can run the NodeJS scripts via shell. Like `exec("node myscript.js")`